# Why shows the search of brew duplicates?

Tags: homebrew, homebrew-cask

I was using the search of brew / homebrew to find the cask "Visual Studio", but the results are all doubled. Why this happend? How can I see only a single hit?

> brew search --casks vis

[Result of brew search (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEHZf.png)

**Update from 2019-05-06**

> brew search --casks vis

Results of brew search (text)

```sh
==> Formulae
aravis                                   travis
elvish                                   vis
libvisio                                 visionmedia-watch
supervisor                               visitors
terraform-provisioner-ansible            visp

==> Casks
dbvisualizer               openvisualtraceroute       vistrails
invisiblix                 provisioning               visual
invisionsync               provisionql                visual-paradigm
inviska-rename             revisions                  visual-paradigm-ce
invisor-lite               scidavis                   visual-studio
invisorql                  sonic-visualiser           visual-studio-code
movist                     viscosity                  visualboyadvance-m
muruslogsvisualizer        visit                      visualvm
```

No doubled results, anymore.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the result of `brew tap`?

Comment: When I type ```brew tab``` I get an error "Unkown command: tab"

Comment: It's `brew tap`.

Comment: Ups, a Typo. When I do ```brew tap``` I get only single catches and no doubles. But the content of the results are different

Comment: What do you mean by "the content of the results are different" ?  Please edit your question and add the output of `brew tap` (as text and not as an image).

Comment: ```brew tap```  
homebrew/cask  
homebrew/core

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`brew tap` list all formula reposity, please untap `caskroom` which is deprecated by `brew untap caskroom/cask`. https://github.com/caskroom

Comment: I was not able to verify the suggestion. ```brew untap``` that is why I cannot, accept the answer

Comment: I can verify that `brew untap` works. (And it looks like you did eventually too @KargWare)